# Removing an object from a nested array if you know the specific location, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array of objects. Something like:

```
[
  {
    item: 'x',
    data: [
      item: 'y',
      data: [
        item: 'z',
        data: [...]
      ]
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

I know the item I want to remove is located at position `[1, 3, 1, 4]`. Is there a faster way to remove that item in the array?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. You should know better with almost 10K rep

Comment: could you log the entire array please and identify which item you want to remove

Comment: I don't think that is valid JS syntax?

Comment: @mplungjan Please be more specific with your issue with my question and I'm happy to address it. I have searched SO and the web but didn't come up with a reasonable answer to my question. I'm always happy adjust my question given direct and constructive feedback.

Comment: @AbdullahAbid the actual array in question is 67 items in total with about 20 elements for each object. Plus the data includes NDA data.

Comment: @52d6c6af Technically you're correct, I'm suing psudocode here simply to say "I have a crazy long and deep array of objects, I need to remove one and a crazy deep location, how?"

Comment: Please post a real sample of the data. Your pseudocode is ambiguous.

Comment: @dcp3450 click edit, then `[<>]` and show us the attempt you made with a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would do it. I'm retrieving a pointer to the very array to mutate, then I mutate it.

What this code doesn't do is :

- Doesn't handle the case the given value is incorrect (bad indexes)
- The keys doesn't exists

What does this code do :

- Handle the case we remove the first item or a deep item
- Handle X nested levels
- mutate the given object

```js
const arr = [{
  item: 'x',
  data: [{
      item: 'y',
      data: [{
        item: 'z',
        data: [],
      }],
    },
    {
      item: 'y2',
      data: [{
        item: 'z',
        data: [{
          item: 'a',
          data: [],
        }, {
          item: 'b',
          data: [],
        }, {
          item: 'toRemove',
          data: [],
        }],
      }],
    }, {
      item: 'y3',
      data: [{
        item: 'z',
        data: [],
      }],
    },
  ],
}];

// /!\ Mutate the given object
function removeAtPos(obj, pos) {
  // Because we look for a pointer, we dont go all in
  // or we would mutate a copy of the data and not the given object data
  const allExceptLast = pos.slice(0, pos.length - 1);

  // ternary is here to handle the case if we have the first item or not
  // First item doesn't start with 'data'
  const ptr = allExceptLast.reduce((tmp, x) => tmp.data ?
                                               tmp.data[x] :
                                               tmp[x], obj);
  
  // Finally remove the wanted part of the array
  (ptr.data || ptr).splice(pos[pos.length - 1], 1);
}

removeAtPos(arr, [0, 1, 0, 2]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: In all of my many years of dev I've never seen the if/else short hand used with a comma `a ? b : c, d` like you did in the reduce. Is that a feature of the shorthand or `reduce`? Where can I read more about that?

Comment: there is the reduce `reduce(func, starting_value);` and then the ternary inside of the function. There is nothing special it. The following is the same : `allExceptLast.reduce((tmp, x) => (tmp.data ?  tmp.data[x] : tmp[x]), obj)`. It's a combo between, Array.reduce, ternary and arrow function single line syntax